# How to create a gridview header that has multi select dropdown list for some of the columns?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu, multi-select

I have a gridview with dropdown in the header. But only single select is possible in gridview.
I want to have multiple selection also in the dropdown.

My code would be something like below:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns = "false"
AllowPaging = "true" PageSize = "10"  Font-Names = "Arial"
Font-Size = "11pt" OnPageIndexChanging = "OnPaging">
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="ContactName" HeaderText="Contact Name" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <HeaderTemplate>
            Country:
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCountry" runat="server"
            OnSelectedIndexChanged = "CountryChanged" AutoPostBack = "true"
            AppendDataBoundItems = "true">
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <%# Eval("Country") %>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="PostalCode" HeaderText="Postal Code" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

So each time a dropdown value is selected, I'll populate the gridview with filtered data in index changed event of dropdown (initial data would be preserved in code itself).

Can anyone help in creating multiple selection for dropdown in gridview header??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

DropDownList itself does not support multiple selection. ListBox may not be a good option in your example, so check out this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18063/Multi-select-Dropdown-list-in-ASP-NET).

You can get an idea from there. I have not tried it though, hope it helps you out.